# Add and remove trailing slash in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write some conditions to add trailing slash or redirect URLs without `.html` and remove `/` from URLs with `.html`

For example:

```
https://www.example.com/page -> https://www.example.com/page/
https://www.example.com/page.html/ -> https://www.example.com/page.html
```

Here is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't spot the rules trying to implement what you describe in that code block

Comment: Why not do it in the PHP area.